# Word VBA to Cut/Paste inlineshape Suddenly Fails

Tags: copy-paste

I’m very new to VBAs so please bear with me. I created the below macro in word to find and replace all inlineshapes as pictures. It has been working fine for weeks but today it errors out when trying to paste cut/paste the third inlineshape. Why would this suddenly fail?

```
Dim i As Integer, oShp As    InlineShape
For i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
Set oShp = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
oShp.Select
Selection.Cut
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=15, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next i
```

Other people I’ve sent the macro and document to can run it without issue.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Uploading a Word document having your issue to a public place for example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t post the document as there is confidential information in it. However, I believe I fixed the issue. 

It seems like my VBA was running faster than word could keep up with (I have a newer computer compared to others). To fix this issue, I added a OnError prompt to display a pause message on error and after hitting ok on the message, the macro retries the paste. This has been consistently working now.